# Where do I find high security dedicated servers?

Tags: sql-server, security, iis, hacking

I'm currently working on a project that will need to protect sensitive data. I use servers on amazon and gigenet, but I'm not sure they are the most secure alternative.

The servers must be a .net applications server and a SQL Server.

BTW by security I mean protected from hackers.

Any suggestions?

update:
if there is no data centers specialized in this kind of security, do you know any security firm that could assist me?

Comment: "BTW by security I mean protected by hackers." What?

Comment: I'm concerned more of hackers than I am for data integrity (like backups), sorry english is not my primary language

Comment: Sounds like you need a fully-managed solution. That's not cheap.

Comment: Apart from the securing the servers, and by that I assume you mean Operating System, Application Severs etc, don't ignore the security of the application itself - has it been designed and written with security in mind?

Comment: Yes, application security I think is the most important part since all the firewalls in the world wont stop a hacker from exploiting a bad software design. Software security I think I've got it, but I am a total noob when it comes to hardware.

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion would be to define your security requirements. do you require pci compliance, hippa, sox, etc?

once you've defined your requirements then speak to various vendors on whether they can meet those requirements.

Comment: To be honest I don't know any of those, googling arround sox seems to be the better option.
Im a noob when it comes to hardware security so I thought maybe some datacenters specialize in this kind of thing.

Comment: Those don't apply if you're not in the US, however similar requirements may be present in other countries.

Comment: @zombiegx: you stated that you need to protect sensitive information. what type of information is it? how do you know it's sensitive if you don't know what legal requirements might exist for protecting it? saying that the data is sensitive and having a legal requirement to secure it are two different things. you need to make sure about it. if you have a legal requirement to secure the data and you don't secure it properly you could wind up in hot water.

Comment: @joequerty: well I can't say exactly what kind of information, but it doesn't have any legal requierements. Still it may be valuable to criminal organizations (which are relentless where I live) and it is very valuable to the clients competitors, so the client asked for high security and is willing to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Check us out at [www.orcsweb.com](http://www.orcsweb.com).  Feel free to send me a message and I can talk further.  While every server on the web has exposure to hackers, we specialize in securing our servers and helping our clients remain secure.

Comment: Please do not use this site for your advertising needs

Comment: @Sam Cogan, it was an honest answer.  I spend time on Stack overflow to answer technical questions, and this one happened to ask a specific question that I had a good recommendation on.  My answer wasn't tainted based on my role with OW.  It was a suggestion that I would honestly give that answers @zombiegx's question specifically.  Price, security and .NET+SQL was specifically asked and discussed, which is what I replied regarding.

Comment: In that case I would contact the OP off-site, by going to his website as listed in his profile and then emailing the OP.

Advertising on the trilogy sites is frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I didn't mean to cross any lines, so it's good to know what is accepted. (btw, I wasn't trying to gain his business as much as answering his question)

Comment: I support your answer. The OP specifically asked for answers that would be in the form of advertisement, it was unavoidable.